# How do i analyse scientific plots programmatically

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I have a graphs that contain a series of curves.I want to know which curve is closest to the origin.

[image]

Given that i have the csv file , how can i process the CSV file in an efficient manner to get the curve closest to origin.For the plot above `AV1` is the expected output.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus my approach seems too complicated.Initially i though i could just sort the size(bpp) in ascending order.Then i check the ssimulacra score for each codec.The codec with the lowest score would be closer to origin

Answer (score 0):

Those look like either exponential decay curves, of the form `y = a * c^x`

This means the logarithm is a linear function: `log y = log a + x * log c`

Perhaps use a linear regression model on the logarithm of "ssimulacra score" to get a slope and intercept for each line, and choose the line having the smallest intercept?

scikit learn has an easy-to-use linear regressor:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html

You can use `pandas` to read the csv file easily.

`pip3 install scikit-learn pandas numpy`

python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
X = df['bpp'].values
y = np.log(df['ssimulacra score'].values)
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X, y)
intercept = reg.intercept_
```

Get the intercept for each line and return the line having the smallest intercept.

Comment: I also recall you can [Find Points of Tangency and Normalcy on a Curve](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/calculus/find-points-of-tangency-and-normalcy-on-a-curve/) and then simply find the point where the normal describes a line running through the origin and measure the distance for each. (you should be able to use an interative method that will converge on the proper point within each set of data fairly quickly)